# How to display only the selected option for several chosen checkboxes of my displayed csv file column headers

Tags: php, csv, checkbox, html-select

```
  <table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" class="sortable" >

   

  <?php
      #read CSV file
      $uploadfile = $_SESSION['uploadCsv'];
      
      if (($handle = fopen($uploadfile, "r")) !== FALSE) {
        $mycsv = array();
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
        $mycsv[] = $data;
        fclose($handle);


      #Find the length of the transposed row

      $row_length = count($mycsv);
      
      echo "<form method='post' action=''><table><tr>";
      echo "<th><input type='checkbox' onClick='toggle(this)' /> Select/Deselect All<br/>
      </th>";
      echo "<th>Column</th>";
      echo "<th>Filter</th>";


      echo "</tr>";

      #Loop through each row (or each line in the csv) and output all the columns for that row
      foreach($mycsv[0] as $col_num => $col)
      {
          

        echo "<tr>";
          
    
    
          for($x=0; $x<1; $x++)
          {
              
          

          echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='lang[]'  value='".$mycsv[$x][$col_num]."' ></td>";
          echo "<td align='center'>"  .$mycsv[$x][$col_num]."</td>";
          echo "<td>
            <select name='method[]' >
             <option value=''>Choose</option>
              <option  value='sum'>Sum</option>
              <option  value='mean'>Mean</option>
              <option  value='standard deviation'>Standard deviation</option>
              <option  value='mode'>Mode</option>
            </select>
              </td>";
          echo "</tr>";
          }
          
      }
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='lang[]' ></td>";
          echo "<td align='center'><input type='text' name='own_column' placeholder='Type your new column here'><br></td>";
          echo "<td><input type='text' name='own_column' placeholder='Own formula'><br></td>";
          echo "</tr>";

          //echo "<tr>";
          //echo "<td colspan='3' align='center'><input type='submit' name='Order'/></td>";
          //echo "</tr>";
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td colspan='3'><div class='wrapper'><br/><br/><input type='button' class='button' value='Input Button'>
          </div></td>";
          echo "</tr>
          <input type='submit' value='submit' name='submit'<table></form>";
            }

  ?>
  </tbody>


 <div style="border:solid 2px red;width:50%;">
 <?php

$package = $_POST['method'];
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

   if(!empty($_POST['lang'])) {

       foreach($_POST['lang'] as $value){
          echo "<tr><td>";
           echo " value : ".$value.'<br/>';
           echo "</td></tr>";

          if(!empty($_POST['method'])) 
           {

           foreach($_POST['method'] as $method){
            if($method == 'sum')
            {
              echo "<tr><td>";
              echo "Sum of ".$value."";
              echo "</td></tr>";
            } else if ($method == 'mean')
            {
              echo "<tr><td>";
              echo "mean of ".$value."";
              echo "</td></tr>";
            }else if ($method == 'mode')
            {
              echo "<tr><td>";
              echo "mode";
              echo "</td></tr>";
            }
            {
              echo"no links";
            }
  
                //echo "method : ".$method.'<br/>';
          }
        
           }

          

       }

   }

  

}
?>
```

[image: My form image]
I am using a form which have check-boxes and select option. Upon import of my csv files using PHP, it displays the data correctly with the column headers. However having real trouble on how to display the CHECKED-boxes with its selected option only.

[image: View image form]
how do I display only the selected option for the selected checkbox. Please help.

Comment: Present your code instead of pictures

Comment: @AksenP Hello, I have added the codes, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your complete foraeach `foreach($_POST['lang'] as $value){...}` section with below code

```
foreach ($_POST['lang'] as $key => $value) {

        $method = $package[$key];
        echo "<tr><td>";
        if ($method == 'sum') {
           echo "Sum of " . $value;
        }
        else if ($method == 'mean') {
           echo "mean of " . $value;
        }
        else if ($method == 'mode') {
           echo "mode";
        }
        else {
           echo"no links";
        }
        echo "</td></tr>";
}
```

Hope this will fix this

Comment: Thank you so much, it did fix the problem. :D

Comment: hello, it is working, but am having a problem. It only works when the first row's checkbox is checked. Meaning if I start to check as from the 2nd row, it displays me no link. Also it is consecutive. Meaning if I checked checkbox 1,2, and 4. here also it displays no link. If i check 1,2,3,4 it works fine. Please help. Thank you